# Proof that for any $u \in L_0$, there exists a $f(q) \in \mathbb{Q}[q]$ for which $f(q)u \in V^{A}$ in global bases theory

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

## Setting

We consider subrings of $\mathbb{Q}(q)$:

- $A_0$: localization at $(q)$
- $A_{\infty}$: localization at $(q^{-1})$
- $A$ = $\mathbb{Q}[q, q^{-1}]$

and free lattices of $\mathbb{Q}(q)$

- $L_0$: free $A_0$- lattice of $\mathbb{Q}(q)$,
- $L_{\infty}$: free $A_{\infty}$- lattice of $\mathbb{Q}(q)$,
- $V^{A}$: free $A$- lattice of $\mathbb{Q}(q)$

## Problem

I don't understand that for any $u \in L_0$ there exists $f(q) \in \mathbb{Q}[q]\backslash \{0\}$ for which $f(q)u \in V^{A}$. Why can we take a nonzero $f(q)$ from $\mathbb{Q}[q]$ not $\mathbb{Q}(q)$. Thank you.

## Remark

This problem is in [Introduction to quantum groups and crystal bases] page 120.